# TwitterAPI in Python - how to return Tweets from only one country?

Tags: python, python-requests, twitter-oauth, twitterapi-python

I am working with the TwitterAPI in Python to access the full tweets archive on Twitter, using some keywords. I read in the Docs that I can specify a location by using place_country and a country code, but for some reason, it does not return the results for only that country. How can I get Tweets from full archive filtered by country?

```
from TwitterAPI import TwitterAPI

r = api.request("tweets/search/fullarchive/:cs",
{"query":"Corona place_country:DE", 
"maxResults": "100", 
"fromDate":"201908230000", 
"toDate":"202004300000"})
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible this way, place_country is not a field that you can use from the standard search api (https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets).

You can probably use "geocode" with a large "radius" and "lang" parameter.

Comment: Yes, but this is not a standard search. It is a premium search which does support `place_country`. https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/overview/premium#AvailableOperators

Comment: I tried using `geocode:46.880260,8.644860,1mi` , but I still receive a Twitter request failed (422) error.

Comment: what's the entire request that you are using?

Answer (score 0):

When you filter by `place_country` you are filtering for tweets that have a specific country code in their payload. This code is set by the user and not a guarantee that the tweet was authored in a particalar country. There are other operators you can include in your filter that may give you better results. https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tutorials/filtering-tweets-by-location

However, what you are trying to achieve is problematic because by default location is turned off and most users do not turn it on.